# MS SQL find table in which change is put by application

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL database with several hundred tables. The database is used by an application. If I Change a Setting in Software Options of this application I know for sure, that this is written into SQL database.

Any way to find out in which table the Change takes place? I could do tests in test database to be sure that no other data Change while toggling those Settings in user Interface of application.

I have no idea how the Change will take place: Could be a new value in a table or Change of a probably numeric value that already is in place.

Comment: Use SQL Profiler

Comment: You can use SQL profiler with necessary filters.

Comment: I tried this out, but did not find desired Looks as if changing the values in this context is hidden in some stored procedues. Maybe I am just not able to use profiler in appropriate way.

Comment: If application modifies data using stored procs, you should look at those procs and analyse what they do. You can find procs in SSMS or you can get then definition of proc with 'sp_helptext YourProcedureName'